# ImageView.setImageBitmap() is not working in onViewCreated() in Fragment(v4)

Tags: android, android-fragments, bitmap, imageview

I am passing the bitmap as a bundle to the Fragment and the following code is not working as expected.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            bitmap = getArguments().getParcelable(BundleHelper.IMAGE);

            mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            //mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            //mImageView.invalidate();
            new ImageSaveAsync(bitmap, getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "to_fragment_camera.jpg").execute();
        }
}
```

I have written this `ImageSaveAsync` to see what is happening to the bitmap. Bitmap is saved to the drive but none of the following has no effect,

```
 mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
 //mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
 //mImageView.invalidate();
```

Is it a bug in Lollipop version? or what am I doing wrong here. Any help please.

Comment: maybe `getArguments()` is returning null?

Comment: @Blackbelt no it is not, that is why I have written `ImageSaveAsync` to save the bitmap and see what is it. it is the correct image. but the only issue is that image is not displaying for the `setImageBitmap()`

Comment: Thanks for the down vote, without explaining why

Comment: Are you using very large bitmaps?
This is possible please have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311288/android-4-0-imageview-setimagebitmap-does-not-work
and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039329/setimagebitmap-has-no-visible-effect

Comment: @SanjeetAjnabee its 203Kb only. I have created a `Async` implementation just to do this in a separate thread. But the effect is the same.:/

Comment: Create the bitmap from the file on the sdcard, set it that way, just to see what happens.

Comment: @r2DoesInc yes it worked, What do you think is the issue with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont parcel the entire bitmap. Get and send a reference to it, maybe the path to the image on the sdcard? Pass that info and rebuild your actual bitmap object in onViewCreated

Comment: Yeah I think that is the way to go for now. And I think since this image is a shared resource, I think the second activity/fragment that is going to use this file, should know that the file is finished creating, I did was I started the second activity after the Asyc is finished saving the file, till then I added  a spinner in the current activity